# What the difference between training on a bent and straight horizontal bar?

Tags: pull-ups, equipment

For pull-ups, some horizontal bars are a straight bar:

[image: Photo of a straight bar for pull-ups.]

While others are bent at the ends:

[image: Photo of a pull-up bar with bent ends.]

When a person is in the upper position (using straight bar) their wrists will be straight, but in lower position their wrists will be tilted. Using a bent bar a person's wrists will always be tilted. The bent bar type is very popular but, on the other hand, I see that barbells use a straight bar.

Which is healthier? Which is better?

Comment: @Ace Cabbie I did some overhaul. If still bad could you mention exact place/s?

Comment: @Ace Cabbie is it still bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know the different muscle groups targeted by using different grip widths, pronated or supinated...

A wide grip on a flat bar pull up works the same muscle groups that a bar with tilted handles works, given that your grip is just as wide. The only difference is that the tilted bar is easier on your wrists and possibly shoulders. The flat bar is generally seen on top of power racks or other equipment where it is not convenient to have an angled bar.

You'll notice that you might be able to do more reps on an angled bar as well given the ease it puts on your joints.

Comment: I hope it's NOT easier on muscles.

Comment: I think it is not, you may have to do more reps or add weight to make it comparable, but the benefit to your joints is great. according to Arnold Schwarzeneggar in an education video, he said that angled bars are better for your muscles than flat bars because it pulls your lats differently. I don't think there's much medical science to back this up; but the greatest bodybuilder prefers angled pullups so should you!